# MongoDB "update()" (Update the document of “Reg Rubio” and “Ian Tayao” by adding the “President” to their Reporting file)

Tags: database, mongodb, insert-update

I use this codes manually

```
db.employees.update({Name: "Reg Rubio"}, {$set : {ReportingTo: ["Vice-President", "President"]}})

db.employees.update({Name: "Ian Tayao"}, {$set : {ReportingTo: ["Secretary", "Vice-President", "President"]}})
```

to update my data. Is their other way to to combine this in one function?

Comment: Might be able to achieve this with `$push`

Answer (score 1):

So.. no.. , there is no way to update two separate documents  using an 2 different inputs in 1 db call.

To optimize network traffic you can use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/), this still executes each update separately in the db but it only sends the request over network once, reducing the overhead for all the traffic. This is the only optimization you can add and for only 2 calls I would say it's somewhat negligent.

Comment: There is a way, if the update operation is the same. If those sets can be rewritten as a `$push: { ReportingTo: "President" }`, then we can totally update both those documents at once.